# Copy system to new fresh install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, backup, restore, dd

I want to wipe my entire hard drive and install a fresh dual-boot Windows7/Ubuntu system, but want to put the entire Ubuntu system as it is now back onto it. The install is located at /dev/sda10.

[image]

I used `dd` to put the partition on an external drive. I don't know if this is the best way because information about how to do this is scattered all across the net which I find confusing. What should I do now? I'm planning on wiping the harddrive by putting a fresh Windows7 install on it but I don't know what to do next to get my copied Ubuntu system back as it was and make it dualbootable.

Comment: do you use `grub`as your boot-loader or windows

Comment: Grub. Windows doesn't even work anymore because I messed some things up, hence the clean install.

Comment: in clean install also you have to choose one boot-loader,what would be that?

Comment: I need to chainload windows if i want to run it. So the windows boot loader gets installed by default. Grub bootloader will be installed afterwards to assist in booting ubuntu. (at least, that's how my system has always worked, I thought it had something to do with EFI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dd` backup was the right thing to do. First fired up `GPartEd` to create a partition on the external disk that was larger than the partition containing the Ubuntu installation that needed backing up. Then opened the console and ran `sudo dd if=/dev/sdaX of=/dev/sdbX bs=512 conv=noerror,sync`.

Next I reinstalled Windows7 and shrunk the Windows partition. Then I fired up a live DVD, from `BIOS` in UEFI mode (else `boot-repair` fails!) containing Ubuntu to create the new EXT4 partition for the saved Ubuntu install to live in. Then entered the following command in the terminal: `sudo dd if=/dev/sdbX of=/dev/sdaX bs=512 conv=noerror,sync`. When `dd` was done I had to check the partition with `GPartEd` because there was unallocated space within the partition of the install and create a new SWAP partition at the end of the disk. Then it was time to get GRUB back by using `boot-repair`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Ran `boot-repair` and chose 'recommended repair'. After following instructions I was able to boot into my old and trusty Ubuntu install, yay. Only one thing left to do and that was point Ubuntu to the SWAP partition. Opened terminal and `GPartEd`, copied the UUID from the swap partition from `GPartEd` and from terminal launched the command: `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab` to edit the UUID of the new location of the SWAP partition that I copied from `GPartEd`. Saved, rebooted, all was back to normal.

Comment: Actually with gpt partitioning dd is not recommended, fine for MBR(msdos). You show an efi partition with Windows so that would be gpt partitioning. And default install of Windows 7 converts drive to MBR and boots in BIOS mode. YOu can convert Windows 7 to flash drive and make it an UEFI installer.

Comment: Why shouldn't I do it like this? I didn't backup windows, just Ubuntu. Could you please elaborate on the downside of this? Because I got it to work (seemingly) without issues.

Comment: More info here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1680929&p=10425340#post10425340

Answer (score 0):

Well first i would install a fresh version of windows 7. Then in Ubuntu installation you should make new partition for the Ubuntu in the /dev/sda10 and configure it I'm kinda new to Ubuntu bot hope this helps you out a bit :)

Comment: The hard part is that there are 4 user accounts, do you suggest to copy all the home folders? And how about all my installed programs? Also, I reasoned as far as you did, but I need some help that's more specific.

Comment: I think copying all the home folders would take up to much space. I suggest to just to copy the most important files. At least i think it's the only solution.

Comment: Actually, isn't there an option to install windows 7 alongside Ubuntu ?

Comment: As far as i know, when you install Windows 7 it wipes the drive clean.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. Hmm i just can't think of anything to help you. Well i hope the people of the internet will find a way for you :D

Comment: @Nkciy84 if you install windows in selected partition /dev/sda4 and run `boot-repair` from Ubuntu live cd you will get you current Ubuntu OS back

Comment: How can I install windows in a partition, if installing windows completely wipes the disk?

Comment: @Mudit can you formulate an answer?